# UIViewController with custom view and weak reference

Tags: ios, objective-c

I prefer to create custom views for all my view controllers. And I define it in code by using weak references for custom views like this:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "MyCustomView.h"

@interface MyViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyCustomView *customView;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (void) loadView
{
    MyCustomView *view = [MyCustomView new];
    self.view = view;
    self.customView = view;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // work with custom view
    self.customView.tableView.delegate = self;
    ....
}

@end
```

Is this the correct use of weak references? Will the application crash or leak, or will there be other problems?

Comment: @Rob I agree which is why I suggested just overriding the `customView` getter method so at least you don't have to cast all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `weak` is fine. You assign your `CustomView` to `self.view` which is defined in the `UIViewController` header as

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *view;
```

so the `view` property has a retaining reference.

There is a possibility that your `view` and `customView` could get out of sync - so I would be tempted to define `customView` as `readonly` and implement the getter as

```
- (CustomView *)customView
{
  return (id)self.view;
}
```

Comment: +1 I'm not crazy about defining the separate property, either. Also, if using NIB or storyboard, I don't like instantiating a `MyCustomView` at all, but rather Rost could just define the top level view's custom class in IB properly to start with and let the standard NIB/scene loading logic take care of it for him.

Comment: @Paul.s Yeah, good idea with method instead of making property. I believe I will use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation of UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926) the view controller's view property has a strong reference to the view. So the custom view object will be retained as long as you don't set the view property to something else. In short, your method works.

Answer (score 0):

As you create the instance from within this controller programatically, you should use a strong reference to set the ownership clearly to this controller.

In the event that you create the view object in IB or soryboard respectively, then a weak reference to the related `IBOutlet` would do.

Comment: Thanks for your replay Herman.
But strong link to created view holds View Controller with self.view property. So, until self.view will be valid `self.customView` will be valid too. After `self.view` will be destroyed by View Controller's internal logic `self.customView` will be destroyed too. I do not see any problems with it in this case.

Comment: Ah, yes. I had overlooked that you are referring to the view object in two 'pointers'. All right. One of them strong should be enough.